# How does this else-if loop track number of words entered in C

Tags: c, word-count

I'm learning C using the K&R book, on a windows machine. I am trying out the program(`bare bones Unix word count`) which counts lines, characters, and words. Although this program correctly counts the number of characters, the no. of lines and words in my output are always 0 and 1, irrespective of what I enter. I also am somewhat stumped by one part of the program, which I'll get to next-

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define IN 1
#define OUT 0

int main()
{
    int c,state, nc,nw,nl;
    nl=nw=nc=0;
    state=OUT;
    while(c=getchar()!=EOF)
    {
        ++nc;
        if(c=='\n')
            ++nl;   

        if(c=='\n'||c=='\t'||c==' ')
            state=OUT;
        else if(state==OUT)
        {
            state=IN;
            ++nw;
        }
    }

    printf("\n No. of characters, lines and words are : %d,%d,%d\n",nc,nl,nw);
    return 0;

}
```

From what it looks, this program is using `nc`, `nl` and `nw`, respectively, to count the number of characters, lines and words entered in the input stream. My understanding of the program logic, thus far, is -

1. `IN` and `OUT` are two variables used to indicate the current state of the program. `IN` indicates that the program is currently 'inside' a word- in other words- no space, newline or tab has been encountered so far in the characters entered. Or so I think.
2. At the very beginning, before the `while` loop, the `STATE` is set to `out`. This indicates that right now, there is no word encountered.
3. When the while loop begins, with every character entered(unless it is EOF-`Ctrl+Z`), the number of character `nc` is incremented. In the first `if statement`, if the character is a newline `'\n'`, `nl` is incremented. This should keep track of the number of lines encountered.
4. The second if statement is used to keep track of whether the program is currently inside a word or not, by setting the `STATE` to 0, whenever there is a blank, newline or tab. I've understood the logic thus far.
5. However, I am completely stumped coming to the else-if. Here, the program checks if `STATE` is `OUT`. Now, `STATE` will be `out` in two conditions:
   when the program runs for the first time, and `STATE` is set to `0` before the while loop.    Example- Consider the input `WORD`. Here, before `W` is encountered, `STATE` is set to `0`.
   Now that `STATE` is `0`, and input is `W` we come to the `else if statement`. The next input after `W` is `O`. So, `STATE` is set to `1`(indicating the program is inside a word), and the word count is incremented.
6. But, since the original input was `WORD`, what happens when `R` is encountered? What is the value of `STATE` now? Is it still `1` because it was set to `1` inside the last else-if statement? But then again, if that is `1`, there is no condition for when `STATE` is `1`.

Lastly, it's obvious that the program is flawed in some way, because in my sample output below, the number of lines and words are always fixed(0 and 1).

```
hello word
good morning
^Z

 No. of characters, lines and words are : 24,0,1
```

I understand that my question is very long, but I'm really stumped and looking for answers to two major points:

- How does the else-if statement logic work.
- Why is the program throwing incorrect output.

Many thanks for your help

Comment: Please check with a debugger. It will give you a clear idea

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are getting wrong input because you are missing parentheses:

```
while((c=getchar())!=EOF)
      ^           ^
```

Without them you always compare the return value of `getchar()` with  `EOF` and assign the result of this comparison to `c`. That is, c will always be either 1 or 0.

Comment: Oh, I missed that. I get the correct output now. However, I'm still not clear on the else-if statement. For the example input WORD, once W and O are encountered, how does the program treat R? If I'm correct, at this stage, STATE is set to IN still, and there are no conditions to deal with this. Then, how does the program deal with R and D of WORD.

Comment: The program will continue in IN state, since he find a " " or "\t" or "\n", so nc++ and that's all. W => nc +1 state = IN, O => nc +1 state = IN, R => nc +1 state = IN, D => nc +1 state = IN.

Comment: This is why 1) you should never use assignment inside expressions, and 2) you should not use K&R for learning purposes, or for any other purpose beyond archaeology and nostalgia. Though this bug is actually mentioned in K&R 2nd edition p19. Such a great book: "Do like this...", "...but wait, actually don't do it, because it's incorrect and bad practice".

Comment: I get your point. I'm also having more and more doubts as I go through K&R. Not to mention that I feel it is more suitable for intermediate to advanced C programmers. Is there any specific material you would suggest for learning purposes?

Answer (score 3):

> How does the else-if statement logic work.

The IF statement check if there is a new line, a space or a tabulation, to CUT a word, so if there is, it put the "state" variable to OUT.

The next loop turn, if the "c" variable is not a new line or tabulation or space, because "state" variable is OUT, the ELSE IF is called.

The ELSE IF increment the nw, because after a space a tabulation or a new line (and if it's not another one) it's a new word. And put back the "state" variable to IN, to return to the IF statement.

EXAMPLE:

"WORD" => "W" -> nc++ nw++ state=OUT, "O" -> nc++ state=IN, "R" -> nc++ state=IN, "D" -> nc++ state=IN

"WO RD" => "W" -> nc++ nw++ state=OUT, "O" -> nc++ state=IN, " " -> nc++ state=OUT, "R" -> nc++ nw++ state=IN, "D" -> nc++ state=IN

And if you want to understand easely, add just after the while statement:

```
while((c=getchar())!=EOF)
{
    printf("number of char = %d, number of words = %d, number or lines = %d, state = %d",nc,nw,nl,state)
```

So you'll see what the code does after each loop turn.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a *very basic* walk-through the *fixed* code. I hope it will answer all of the original questions.

The only other suggestion is to enable and check compiler *warning* messages, as they often have clues about potent sources of errors. In fact, `gcc`, and `clang` will warn about the original program and suggest the correct fix.

Include the standard (std) Input/Output header files

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

Use the pre-processor to define to (constant) *macros*, which are used to represent the state of either being `IN`-side a word, or `OUT`-side a word. The definition for "outside" means that the current character (c) is a white space in this program.

White space being a character that does not display anything, but may modify the output, such as moving to the next character location (space), to the next tab stop (tab), or advancing to the next line (newline).

```
#define IN 1
#define OUT 0
```

Being a simple program, the program is located in the `main` function. That is okay for a short program like this one, but not a good idea in larger, more complex programs.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int c;     /* This is a 'current' character being read from input */
    int state; /* The state of being either IN- or OUT-side of a word. */
    int nc;    /* Count of number of characters read */
    int nw;    /* Count of number of "words" */
    int nl;    /* Line count */
    nl = nw = nc = 0; /* Initialize the counts to zero */
    state = OUT;  /* Begin with the word 'state' being OUT-side of a word */
```

Get a single character from standard input (stdin), assign it to
the variable `c`. This is done first because of the (added) parenthesis enclosing the expression `c = getchar()`. Then the result of this assignment (which is equal to `c`) is compared to EOF (end of file).

*While* the contents of `c` are *not* equal to `EOF`, the `while` loop's body executes repeatedly, until the `getchar()` does assign an `EOF` to `c`.

```
    while ( EOF != (c = getchar()) )
    {
```

Since you have a new character increment the character count, `nc`, variable by one.

```
        ++nc;
```

If `c` is a newline, increment the number of lines, `nl`, count.

```
        if (c == '\n')
            ++nl;
```

If the variable `c` is a newline, tab, or space, then sent the `state` variable to `OUT`, because they indicate that `c` is not part of a "word."

```
        if (c == '\n' || c== '\t' || c == ' ') {
            state = OUT;
        }
```

If the previous `if` statement did **not** evaluate to true, follow the `else` statement.
The else statement consists of a second `if` statement which evaluates whether `state` is equal to `OUT`. If so, then execute the next block.

```
        else if (state == OUT)
        {
```

This block contains the two statements, set `state` to `IN`, and increment the value of `nw` (word count).

```
            state = IN;
            ++nw;
        } /* end of "else if" block */
    } /* end of while loop block */
```

After `getchar()` returns an `EOF` (end of file), and the while loop ends, the program prints this summary output before returning zero to the parent process (don't worry about that here, it's just house-keeping) and ending the program.

```
    printf("\n No. of characters, lines and words are : %d, %d, %d\n", nc, nl, nw);

    return 0;
} /* end of main */
```