# Role of else if (state == OUT) in C word count

Tags: c, if-statement, word-count

I'm learning C following the book "The C Programming Language" - K&R;
I found myself stuck in the understanding of the role of `else if (state == OUT)`:

```
#define IN 1
#define OUT 0

main () 
{
    int c, nw, state; 
    
    state = OUT;
    nw = 0;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t')
            state = OUT;
        else if (state == OUT) {
            state = IN;
            ++nw;
        }
    }
    printf ("%d", nw);
}
```

In the word counting program, I mean, in the way I read it there must be something I am doing wrong, because I fail to understand why this makes the difference, from simple `else`, since `state = OUT` is already default condition; but in practice I observe that it does, because if I write just `else`
then the statement `state = IN; ++nw` will count characters and not words;

from the way I read it, the loop is saying that for each input character (stored in the variable c), if it is a space, a new line, or a tab, then it's value is zero, everything else, will be 1, so I fail to see how it is grouping characters into words, because `state` was `OUT` already before the loop, so how is `else if (state == OUT)` getting the program to put the characters into one word?

I have been thinking whole night about it but I couldn't find an answer in my thoughts, nor in the book

Comment: Maybe add a `printf()` at the top of the loop to find out what it does? (BTW `nc` != `nw` )

Comment: The program counts the number of words on the *transition* of state from whitespace to printing character.

Comment: state is IN when reading a word. Transition to OUT is the end of a word

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does this else-if loop track number of words entered in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24243688/how-does-this-else-if-loop-track-number-of-words-entered-in-c)

Comment: I wonder, does it miss the count of last word?

Comment: @Hasturkun I read this but it doesn't answer my question, `state` is `OUT` by default no? So, if I read this program, I would "translate" it like this: "for each input character (stored in `c` variable) `if` the input isn't a space, a tab, or new line, and the the state is `OUT`, the `state` is `IN`, so it's value is `1`, afterwards, add `+1` to `nw` - so, for me, it still looks like it should add +1 per each character, so it would be equivalent to simple `else { state IN; ++nw; }`...

Comment: @InQusitive No, it doesn't.  It increments the count when it sees the first character of a new word, i.e. when it transitions from OUT to IN.  Your concern would only be a potential problem if it incremented the count when transitioning from IN to OUT, which wouldn't really make sense.

Comment: No, there is no "default state".  `state` is initialized to `OUT`, but once you read a non-space character it is assigned the value `IN`.  It does not change on the next iteration until it is explicitly assigned.  That is the point of the variable.  It tells you what state you are in: either IN a word or not.

Comment: @TomKarzes: What if the last character of a file is not space,tab,newline? It's possible right? So state=IN and it won't count that word yet.

Comment: @WilliamPursell ok, but why this is not working in this way: `if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t') state = OUT; else { state = IN; ++nw; }`; isn't it telling to exclude each `' ', '\n', '\t'` and set everything in between as a fixed value of 1 (IN) as well?

Comment: @GregoryMagnus Because you do not want to increment `nw` unless you are transitioning. If you're already in a word, the `++nw` will recount that word.

Comment: @InQusitive If the last character is not a white space character, then it is part of a word and will have been counted.  When the *first* character of a word is seen, the state must have been OUT, the word is counted, and the state is changed to IN.  Your example is not a problem.

Comment: @TomKarzes: But to make it as a word, it has to come through the while check in next iteration and since it's already end of file, it won't go inside and it won't execute `if` or `else if`?

Comment: @InQusitive The code works.  You keep making the mistake of thinking the current word won't be counted until the following iteration.  That is incorrect.  In between words (and at the start), the state is OUT.  When the *first* character of the new word is seen, two things happen:  (1) the word is *counted*, and (2) the state is changed to IN.  After that, the word has been counted, regardless of what comes next.  Why don't you compile it and see for yourself?  Again, the word is counted as soon as the *first* character of the word is seen.  The *first*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To count words, we want to increment the count, with `++nw`, only once per word.

If we write:

```
        if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t')
            state = OUT;
        else {
            state = IN;
            ++nw;
        }
```

then `++nw` will be executed every time `c` is not one of the white-space characters space, new-line, or tab. However, by writing:

```
        if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t')
            state = OUT;
        else if (state == OUT) {
            state = IN;
            ++nw;
        }
```

then `++nw` will not be executed when we are already in a word (state is `IN`). It will be executed only when we are out of a word (state is `OUT`) and are going into a new word (because `c` is not one of the white-space characters). Thus, `++nw` is executed only when we start a new word, not for each character in the word.

Comment: so the program is actually saying that for each input character (in c variable), if the state is OUT for any other reason than being ' ', '\n', '\t' -> then it will set it to state IN, so that it won't count all characters; so also the state = IN statement is important, because without it, it will also count each character

Answer (score 2):

```
cccc cc    c c  cccccc cc
^    ^     ^ ^  ^      ^
    |  |    | |       |  |
```

These are the two ways to count words - only the transitions count.

Geometrically this is easy and intuitive: every `c` that has a white space to its left.

But if you step (once, blindly) through each element, you only have to store the last character, which corresponds to the "left". This minimal memory makes this algorithm a state machine.

When you hit a letter, you only count it if you come from OUTside a word, but at the same time set the state to INside, so the next letter does not get counted. The next space then will set the trigger to "OUT".

Answer (score 1):

This statement is checking character (`c`) values:
`if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t')`

and if any character (`c`) is a space or newline or tab then the `state` value is changed to `OUT`.

This statement `else if (state == OUT)`  is checking the value of `state` whenever a character (`c`) is **not** a space, newline or tab.

The assumption of the program is that all words are separated by a space, newline or tab character and is at least one character long.

Punctuation characters such as `:;,.?!` etc. are included as legitimate characters for words.

Use of `getchar` ensures that at least one character is read.
The program will complete when it detects an End Of File character i.e. no further input.

The word count is increased on the first character that is not space, newline or tab.

Comment: ok, but if the point is excluding the spaces, tabs and new lines, then why isn't it the same to tell `if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t') state = OUT; else { state = IN; ++nw; }`? If you write it like this, it's counting each single character between spaces, not words, so why I need to set an explicit condition of `state == OUT`, when it was already set like this before the loop?

Comment: @GregoryMagnus: Because you do not want the program to count each single character. Its purpose is to count words, not to count characters.

Answer (score 0):

This program counts words by modeling a very simple state machine with two states:

```
OUT: We have not read a character that is part of a word
 IN: We have read a character that is part of a word
```

The number of words is determined by the number of times we *transition* from the `OUT` to the `IN` state.  Given an output like `"This   is a  test"`, the transitions work like this:

```
This   is a     test
^+++v--^+v^v----^+++
```

where `+` represents the `IN` state, `-` represents `OUT` state, `^` represents the transition from `OUT` to `IN`, and `v` represents the transition from `IN` to `OUT`.   The number of words is equal to the number of times we see `^`.

In order to know whether or not we're making the transition from the `OUT` to the `IN` state, we have to check the current value of `state` when we see a non-whitespace character; hence, the

```
else if (state == OUT)
```

as the alternate branch instead of a plain `else`.  Otherwise we'd increment `nw` for every non-whitespace character, rather than on the transition from `OUT` to `IN`.